# jquery and page.isvalid in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

After struggling for a few days, i was able to implement a multi step wizard using jquery form wizard/validation plugin and asp.net.
I noticed one gotcha while testing.(nothing do with the jquery plugins) 
When the user first clicks the final submit button, jquery validator kicks in and all the validation messages are spitted out right. However, submit button is still active and user can still click on it which obviously is not good.

Should i just check for Page.IsValid method on code behind ? Is there a better solution, like disabling/enabling submit button in javascript? Whats the best way to handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what method you use to validate your form on the client side, you should *always* validate it again on the server side. It is very, very easy to get around client side validation so you should get in to the habit of validating the data on both sides.

That being said, I prefer to keep the submit button enabled. The validation method should prevent the form from being submitted and the validation/error messages should be clear enough to let the user know what needs to be fixed before the form can be submitted.